# C++ expected primary-expression before "int"

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Homework assignment for the week is to create a basic c++ program asking a user to input a length in feet and inches and then output them in centimeters; the catch is we are to create an exception and have it handle it for if the user enters a negative number or a character. I have the code written but when it compiles i get the error:

In function 'int main()': expected primary-expression before "int" expected ')' before "int" on line 19.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const double centimetersPerInch = 2.54; //named constant
const int inchesPerFoot = 12; //named constant

int main ()
{
    int feet;
    int inches; //declared variables    
    int totalInches;
    double centimeters;
    //statements
cout << "Enter two integers one for feet and " << "one for inches: ";
cin >> feet >> inches;
try
{
     if ( int feet, int inches < 0.0 )
        throw "Please provide a positive number";
cout << endl;

cout << "The numbers you entered are " << feet << " for feet and " << inches << " for inches. " << endl;               
    totalInches = inchesPerFoot * feet + inches;     

cout << "The total number of inches = " << totalInches << endl;                   
    centimeters = centimetersPerInch * totalInches;

cout << "The number of centimeters = " << centimeters << endl;   
}
catch (char* strException)
{
      cerr << "Error: " << strException << endl;
}

    return 0;
}
```

I figure it is something simple that I am overlooking but I just can't figure out what my issue is. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw, string literals are `const char[]`, not `char *`.

Answer (score 8):

In

```
if ( int feet, int inches < 0.0 )
```

you sort-of implicitly re-declare two integer variables you have declared before. You shouldn't do that. Instead, simply use them:

```
if (feet, inches < 0.0 )
```

Now still, this is probably not what you meant. You probably meant to say something like this:

```
if (feet < 0.0 || inches < 0.0 )
```

Comment: `if (feet, inches < 0.0 )` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Except that it means a different thing :)))))

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that's a whole different issue :P

Comment: Thank you thank you, I knew it was something simple that my befuddled brain was not processing...it complies and runs...thanks again!

Comment: @Angie: If this answers your question entirely, don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut the words `int` inside of the if statement beginning your try-block.

And you need to use a `||` instead of a comma. i.e. `feet < 0.0 && inches < 0.0`